# Magento2 : Bulk Product upload csv for compare Prodcut Sku then result back to in CSV

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to upload csv for compare Product Sku then result back to in CSV

I want to create a simple backend from there  backend which can Upload CSV and 
populate Product Collection which not available set an array and return back to csv format.